# Exemption from language requirements for MSc?

Tags: masters, language

My friend found a MSc program in Germany whose professors guaranteed to him full English courses plus they would let him write his thesis in English. However, the admission office at the University asks for a high level (C1) of German language proficiency.

Up until now he did not have any luck in explaining this to the people in the Admission office. My question is - is it possible for an exemption of the language requirements to happen, or would you advice that this sounds like a time wasted? Have you heard of any case that this was a obstacle, but it got solved?

Comment: "... they would let **him** write **my** thesis in English." Sounds suspicious to me.

Comment: Mistake. Fixed.

Comment: @BirdMars I'm not sure what you expect with your bounty. The answer of Arno is really accurate and quite optimistic to my opinion. For context: I have spent almost 5 years in german universities until now and met a fair amount of students coming from abroad in order to complete their MSc.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Based on my experience with German universities, your friend attempting to convince the admissions office will be near hopeless. One of the professors he has been in touch with could have a decent chance though.